# Oracle database connection using SSL cwallet.sso in java

Tags: java, jdbc, ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, ojdbc

I'm trying to connect the oracle database using the Java program. The database is needed to connect with the SSL cwallet.sso file. when I tried to connect it pops out of class not found an exception. Also, I am not sure that my code is correct or not.

Code:

```
package com.erplogic.lms.dabasehelper;
```

import com.erplogic.lms.utilities.*;

```
  import java.security.Security;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.text.DateFormat;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.Properties;

public class DatabaseConnection {
// ORACLE DATABASE Connection

private Connection con;
private final String oracleDriver;
private final String connectionString;
private final String userName;
private final String password;

public DatabaseConnection() {
    oracleDriver = PropertyFileHandler.PROPERTY_OBJECT.getProperty("ORACLE_DATABASE_DRIVER");
    connectionString = PropertyFileHandler.PROPERTY_OBJECT.getProperty("DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING");
    userName = PropertyFileHandler.PROPERTY_OBJECT.getProperty("DATABASE_USER_NAME");
    password = PropertyFileHandler.PROPERTY_OBJECT.getProperty("DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD");
}

public Connection connectOracleDatabase() {
    try {
    
        log4jHandler.infoLogger("Connecting To Database ::", PropertyFileHandler.class);
        //step1 load the driver class
        System.out.println(oracleDriver);
        //Class.forName(oracleDriver);
        //properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", userName);
        props.setProperty("password", password);
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\sapUAT\\ssl_wallet\\cwallet.sso");
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","SSO");
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","D:\\sapUAT\\ssl_wallet\\cwallet.sso");
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","SSO");
        props.setProperty("oracle.net.authentication_services","(TCPS)");
        Security.addProvider(new oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider());
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());



        //step2 create  the connection object
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,props);
        System.out.println(con);
        log4jHandler.infoLogger("Database Connection Success ::", PropertyFileHandler.class);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log4jHandler.errorLogger("Database Connection Issue :: " + e.getMessage(), PropertyFileHandler.class);
        Email emailTrigger = new Email();
        //emailTrigger.triggerEmailWithoutAttachment("Database Connection Issue","Please check VPN is Connected Or Not \n"+e.getMessage());


       emailTrigger.triggerEmailWithOutAttachmentRohaGroup("Finnone SAP Interface : Database Connection Issue : " +DateFunction.getTheCurrentSystemDate(),EmailTemplates.messageBodyForDatabaseDown());

        System.exit(0);

    }

    return con;
 }
 }
```

ERROR : **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/crypto/core/AuthenticationException**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar and osdt_cert.jar in the class-path along with ojdbc jar. These jars can be downloaded from OTN/maven.

Comment: Is it possible to connect database using .PEM file